# Python 2.7- separating b,g,r in an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

Ok, so what I want to do is go through an entire array of pixels, and for each pixel grab the green value, blue value and red value. This is so later I can see patterns between them.

So, this is what my code looks like.

```
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format='bgr', use_video_port =True):
data=frame.array
rawCapture.truncate(0)
ColourCount = Calculations(data)
```

Ok, now that was just to show you what the general code is. This is where it gets tricky. Also, if that doesn't work for you guys on Pc, just use any opencv, I'm sure they save the data the same.

```
Calculations(data):
for n in data:
    for s in n
        B=s[0]
        G=s[1]
        R=s[2]
```

Then when I print these, it doesn't yield the result I want.

So s is like [0, 14, 0]
And B is like [0, 0, 0] as is the others. (those are just examples, although the values aren't getting high for some reason.

Now what I would like, is to split it so B is the blue channel, G is the green channel, etc.

So for the N example:
    B= 0
    G= 14
    R = 0

So how do I achieve this?

I want single integers, but it's sending me back an entire pixel nearly?

EDIT: I believe part of my mistake before was that the item I was collecting was in fact a row instead of a pixel. So I put another for loop in, as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split() function.

```
Calculations(data):
bgr = cv2.split(data)
B = bgr[0]
G = bgr[1]
R = bgr[2]
```